# UITableView with custom cells empty

Tags: swift, uitableview

I am trying to test my friendTableView with a sample array of friends. I have created a custom cell class to show a profile picture and a label for the friends' names. However, when I run the app, the table view is completely empty. Here is my view controller class:

```
import UIKit

class FriendsVC: UIViewController {

    //var friends: [Friend] = User.current.friends
    var friends = [Friend]()
    var groups: [Group] = []
    
    @IBOutlet weak var friendTableView: UITableView!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var groupTableView: UITableView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        friends = [Friend(uid: "aslfkjlaskdfj", firstName: "Jane", lastName: "Johnson", phone: "+18003473874", available: true), Friend(uid: "asdfkhkjshkjh", firstName: "Bob", lastName: "Odenkirk", phone: "+18003474874", available: true), Friend(uid: "aslfkjlaskdfj", firstName: "Walt", lastName: "White", phone: "+18003273874", available: true)]

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        friendTableView.delegate = self
        friendTableView.dataSource = self

}
```

My extension:

```
extension FriendsVC: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        
        return min(User.current.friends.count, Constants.maximumFriendsDisplayed)
    
    }
    
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        
//        if tableView == friendTableView {
        
            let friend = friends[indexPath.row]
        
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: Constants.Identifiers.friendCell, for: indexPath) as! FriendCell
            
            cell.setFriend(friend: friend)
            return cell
```

And my cell model class:

```
import UIKit
import InitialsImageView

class FriendCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var profilePic: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var friendNameLabel: UILabel!
    
    func setFriend(friend: Friend) {
        if let pic = friend.profilePic {
            self.profilePic.image = pic
        } else {
            self.profilePic.setImageForName(friend.firstName + friend.lastName, backgroundColor: nil, circular: true, textAttributes: nil)
        }
        
        friendNameLabel.text = friend.firstName + " " + friend.lastName
        
    }
    
}
```

I'm not getting any errors, just an empty table view. what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not reloading TableView

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        friends = [Friend(uid: "aslfkjlaskdfj", firstName: "Jane", lastName: "Johnson", phone: "+18003473874", available: true), Friend(uid: "asdfkhkjshkjh", firstName: "Bob", lastName: "Odenkirk", phone: "+18003474874", available: true), Friend(uid: "aslfkjlaskdfj", firstName: "Walt", lastName: "White", phone: "+18003273874", available: true)]

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        friendTableView.delegate = self
        friendTableView.dataSource = self
        friendTableView.reloadData()

}
```

Try to return friends.count

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        
        return friends.count
    
    }
```

Comment: Tried it, no change :/

Comment: updated answer ... first we check if it works or not ...